# How to make a USB hub with 48 ports or more?

Tags: usb

I want to make a USB hub with 48 ports or more, because I have many flash drives. I need to switch different flash drives to do different things.

The USB hub communicates with the computer through the usb cable. And it is powered by usb cable or separate power cable. I don't care about transfer speed，but hopefully it will work stably for a long time, at least a week.

I have searched a long time, and found much information that didn't meet my requirements.

Reference links：

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4oV-k8ApD8
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCGtIrkwDsc

How can I make a 48 port USB hub?

Comment: Please show what you have found so far and why it does not meet your needs. Also state your needs? USB Version? Power? What is the upstream connection?

Comment: Probably many hubs in one box. If you ever saw a 9-port hub for sale, it was 2 5-port hubs in one box. Which is sometimes annoying because you're only allowed to have 5 hubs between the computer and the device.

Comment: Big, massive, hurking power supply.

Comment: You would find a USB hub chip you like, and make it into a product. Possibly more than one chip in the circuit, like those 9-port hubs.

Comment: What are your performance requirements? Usually, if you need a lot of ports in a system, it's better to build it with multiple USB host controllers.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, this is incorrect. USB hubs can have 127 downstream ports, per USB standard, just no one is making this kind of silicon, see https://superuser.com/a/1122852/620011

Comment: See variants here, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/436665/117785

Answer (score 0):

If all you have at the start is a USB port then you can have a "tree of hubs", but that will probably disappoint you as you will be choking them in speed. Crudely, each of those ports will have 1/48 of the full speed.

A better approach is to make or find a PCIexpress card with so many or as close as possible, like 24 or 16, that you could split each of them. The difference is the PCI cards, especially if 32x have many GB/s and can handle the full traffic of so many USB ports.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  :)